# Java Deserialization issue

Tags: java, vulnerability

I have been reading about the Java deserialization vulnerability which leads to Remote Code Execution attack. Many public exploits are even available to do the attack.

I didn't find any tutorial describing on how does an attacker exploit the vulnerability. If I make a deserialization program, then how can I exploit it to perform RCE?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at the public exploits to learn how they exploit the vulnerability and then ask a more specific question about anything you don't understand.

As a place for you to start, somebody [made a page on github](https://github.com/GrrrDog/Java-Deserialization-Cheat-Sheet) that summarizes all the talks and guides.  The published exploit of OpenNMS using ysoserial is about as simple as you are going to get.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this talk, it explains everything pretty well.

https://speakerdeck.com/frohoff/appseccali-2015-marshalling-pickles-how-deserializing-objects-can-ruin-your-day